# Facing delay in response from the hub using SignalR ReactNative in ANDROID

Tags: android, react-native, timer

Error: Setting timers for multiple minutes isn't handled properly in React Native on Android: it keeps the Timing module awake instead of relying on the system waking us up when the timer should go off.

Note:Same timer is working fine in iOS build.

Comment: What is it that you want to achive? Timers can be tricky on react native and they can cause timing and leak memory issues. Can you share your code?

Comment: Actually we are using SignalR for hub connection and facing 3-4 mins delay in response particularly in ANDROID device